# react function component issue with usEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Sometimes I have to use some native js libaray api, So I may have a component like this:

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.querySelector('#container')
    const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
    h1.innerHTML = 'h1h1h1h1h1h1'
    container.append(h1)
    h1.onclick = () => {
      console.log(state)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(state => state + 1)}>{state}</button>
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Above is a simple example. I should init the lib after react is mounted, and bind some event handlers. And the problem is coming here: As the above shown, if I use `useEffect()` without `state` as the item in dependencies array, the value `state` in handler of onclick may never change. But if I add `state` to dependencies array, the effect function will execute every time once state changed. Above is a easy example, but the initialization of real library may be very expensive, so that way is out of the question.

Now I find 3 ways to reslove this, but none of them satisfy me.

1. Create a ref to keep state, and add a effect to change it `current` every time once `state` changed. (A extra variable and effect)
2. Like the first, but define a variable out of the function instead of a `ref`. (Some as the first)
3. Use class component. (Too many this)

So is there some resolutions that solve problems and makes code better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've summarised the options pretty well. There's only one option i'd like to add, which is that you could split your code up into one effect that initializes, and one effect that just changes the onclick. The initialization logic can run just once, and the onclick can run every render:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0)
const h1Ref = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container')
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
  h1Ref.current = h1;
  // Do expensive initialization logic here
}, [])
useEffect(() => {
  // If you don't want to use a ref, you could also have the second effect query the dom to find the h1
  h1ref.current.onClick = () => {
    console.log(state);
  }
}, [state]);
```

Also, you can simplify your option #1 a bit. You don't need to create a useEffect to change `ref.current`, you can just do that in the body of the component:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
const ref = useRef();
ref.current = state;
useEffect(() => {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  // ...
  h1.onClick = () => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I forget that I could change the `current` of a ref in function body, this makes code better!

Comment: By the way, I think bind event listener in useEffect with a state as dependency is not good. This case use `onclick`, if I use `addEventListener()`, I have to write a clean function as return to remove listener, that's really bad.

Comment: `if I use addEventListener(), I have to write a clean function as return to remove listener, that's really bad` I agree you'd need to do that, but why's that "really bad'? If you're talking about performance, adding and removing event listeners is very lightweight. Basically the same as pushing and popping from an array.

Comment: Because I didn't have to. Without react, I just bind it once and it's all over. But now, I need to bind it and remove it once state changed, and do that again and again. All of them are extra costs though they may be very cheap.